# How to change the row color on the basis of column value in power automate "Send Email" action?

Tags: html, css, excel, power-automate

I want to attach excel table in email body via power automate which I was able to do. But I want to highlight rows that contain specific column value. Something like this.[image]
My current flow looks like this.

[image]

Compose code looks like this.

```html
<style>
table {
  border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: auto;
}
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 10px;
}
table tbody td {
  font-size: 13px;
}
table thead {
  background: #1C6EA4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
}
table thead th {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
}
table thead th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
table thead th.topic {
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

My logic is if first column value = "State" row background color blue and text-color white but I could not implement the logic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following websites may help: https://alextofan.com/2019/02/14/flow-how-to-change-the-style-of-your-html-table-in-flow/  https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Conditionally-highlight-1-cell-in-a-html-table/td-p/829079 https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Conditional-formatting-on-cell-value-based-colours-in-HTML-table/td-p/1701961